# call and post value webservice with jquery mobile or phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, web-services, cordova

i desing my page with jquerymobile and i do native app for android with phonegap. it is working but in my page i have form and i have to get some value and after that i will send value/data with webservice. How can i do that ? i research about that but i found some documents these are so complex and not working. so do you have some exapmle/sample ? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried any code? Sharing the code that you used will help to proceed further..

Comment: You could use [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) since you are using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $.ajax({
    url: PublishUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {


    },
    error: function (x, y, z) {
        alert(x.responseText +" "+ x.status);
    }
});
```

**postData** = data in json format
**PublishUrl** =  url where you need to call the service

This same can be used to post and call too, you can change type to "GET"  and loop through in your success block

Comment: i use wcf service and its give me xml =/

Answer (score 0):

Submit form data on click button add following code

```
var ajax_call = web_service_URL;
var str = $('#frm_id').serialize();;

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: ajax_call,
   data: str,
   cache:false,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(response){   



     }
 }).done(function() {

 })
 return false;
```

Comment: i use wcf service and its give me xml =/