# Create mobile application with data loading from internal xml/json files

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, web-applications, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm planning to write a mobile application using my skills from website development. For that; phonegap and jQuery come to my mind. Now the main issue faced is to have the index.html loading its contents from a xml/json file.

Comment: 0read about [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Create an ajax call use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329295/call-and-post-value-webservice-with-jquery-mobile-or-phonegap/20329708#20329708 and then make a function in the success block to dynamically add the data use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698779/how-to-display-data-to-html-using-javascript/20698930#20698930

Comment: @-Omar It seems that we can not use $.ajax outside of a server technologie.
@RohitTiwari we are not planning to use sqlwebserver nor localstorage We have a set of xml file that we would like to use directly in our app in built

Comment: @N'KauhNathan-RégisBodje this was just an example, you can tweak it per your need :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// url for json data source
var url = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&q=russia';
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
   console.log(data); // place your json in some place
});
```

For testing it in a browser let's add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in server response header.